# HTML5 - Android Tablet - INPUT TYPE NUMBER

Tags: android, html, types, input, numbers

Good night guys,

I am using input type with numbers, but the field is a currency value with comma and point. More Android opens the keyboard with only numbers without comma or point.

Example error on Galaxy Tab 10.1

http://pastie.org/5063487

or

http://jsfiddle.net/F8EPw/

Comment: You could consider using jQuery UI's `spinner` plugin to handle the currency values - http://tjvantoll.com/2012/07/15/native-html5-number-picker-vs-jquery-uis-spinner-which-to-use/.  You wouldn't get the correct keyboard on Android but you would get spinners that would work with the currency input anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `<input type="number" step="any" />`
Further explanations can be found [here](http://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/)

Comment: Hello Pascal,

I had already tested this solution, even using pattern without result. When I try to tell dot or comma, simply runs out of action.

Examples:

<input type="text" name="test" pattern="\d*" />
<input type="number" step="0.01" pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?">
<input type="number"
       min="0"
       max="999"
       step="0.000001" pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?"
>

Comment: Ahh i using Android 3.2 em Samsung Tab 10.1

Comment: @WilliamReisFernandes, i'm in the same situation. I've tested everything: step, min, max, pattern, etc. You also say you've tried everything, but then you have marked the answer as good. Did you find the solution? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: New bugs :S - Example error on Galaxy Tab 10.1 - I do not think a solution. disappointed :(

http://pastie.org/5063487

or

http://jsfiddle.net/F8EPw/

Answer (score 1):

I had already tested this solution, even using pattern without result. When I try to tell dot or comma, simply runs out of action.

Examples:

```
<input type="text" name="test" pattern="\d*" />

<input type="number" step="0.01" pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?">

<input type="number" min="0" max="999" step="0.000001" pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?" />
```

Ahh i using Android 3.2 em Samsung Tab 10.1